# iOS 5 won't redirect to Appstore

Tags: ios, ios5, redirect, app-store

We have an iOS SDK that is hosted within different applications. Inside the app I have a redirection to Appstore. The redirect is from html code (Webview within the application).
Redirection works fine for iOS 6 but fails for iOS 5.
The app store redirect is to something like: http://itunes.apple.com/app/id447553564?mt=8.
Is there different configurations / settings / changes from iOS 5 to iOS 6 that could make this happen?
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your http:// to itms://

like this:
    itms://itunes.apple.com/app/id447553564?mt=8